# How can I output a default render object before a marker click?

Tags: shiny, leaflet

This code outputs a text each time I click a marker on my map. However, during the first execution no text appears as I haven't clicked any marker yet. How can I tell it to render a default text before any marker is clicked on the map (let's say, name = "A")?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data<-data.frame(lat = c(42.5, 43.1),
                 lon = c(3.14, 2.1),
                 name = c("A", "B"))

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map"),
      textOutput("ts")
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map<-
    renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(data = data) %>% 
        fitBounds(~ min(lon), ~ min(lat), ~ max(lon), ~ max(lat)) %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lat = ~ lat, lng = ~ lon,
                         layerId = ~ name)
    })
  
  click <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    click$marker <- input$map_marker_click
    
    output$ts <-
      renderText({
        print(click$marker$id[1])
      })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `renderText` outside of `observeEvent`, so that it is printed by default.

Put that in the server outside of `observeEvent`:

```
output$ts <- renderText({
  print("A")
})
```